# How to set a autoscroll from ASP.NET Core MVC #control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-5.0

I am having an HTTP Post function in ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC which is responsible for saving the values and redirect to index page with query string parameter (`?CID=66`)

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SaveClubPlayer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveClubPlayer(ClubsPlayer aClubsPlayer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (PortalDBContext aPortalDBContext = new PortalDBContext())
        {
            //Logic
            await aPortalDBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClubFederation", new { CID = 66});

}
```

Upon submit I am getting URL in below format.

```
https://localhost:44324/ClubFederation?CID=5
```

But my requirement is in below format, is there any possibility from server side ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC:

```
https://localhost:44324/ClubFederation?CID=5#controlid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "ClubFederation", action = "Index", CID = 66}) + "#" + controlid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on `Hamed Naeemaei's answer`, I would like to add that you need to add [HttpGet("Index")] to the page method you want to jump to.

Because after using `return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "ClubFederation", action = "Index", CID = 66}) + "#" + controlid);`, we get the url like below.

```
https://xxx:port/ClubFederation/Index?CID=66#controlid
```

After add [HttpGet()], the url should be you want.

---

*Test Code And Result*

[image]

[image]